# Net Core: Solutions to Update History Tables in Application Design

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server, .net-core

Our company did not properly design Address Record Code Module. Developers are updating `Address` SQL table with Multiple Service Methods, and are not updating `AddressHistory` Sql table. They're asking me to unify/resolve the issue :) . What are some methods to resolve this?

I came up with these 3 alternatives. Just curious if there are anymore anyone can think of?

1) Create a common Repository function which updates Address History? Ask everyone to utilize this and app this to their code?

2) Should I create an IAuditable Interface  that will intercept DB `SaveChanges` and update Address History?

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5216095/Entity-Framework-with-Audit-Tables?

3) Utilize SQL Triggers (Sql temporal tables do not apply history changes in a customized manner)

Currently applying Net Core 2, Entity Framework, and SQL server

Comment: The solution you ultimately decide on will depend on factors like performance and maintainability.

Comment: Hi @RobertHarvey well my question is, is there another solution I am missing, maybe #4 or #5?

Comment: Basically you already know the answer. Triggers. I don't often use triggers, but this seems an appropriate use case for them. You cannot circumvent the trigger, and this prevents a lot of code changes elsewhere.

Comment: hi @GregBurghardt thought triggers would be the worst option due to performance reasons, sql optimization

Comment: I've learned through the years that *thinking* something is a performance problem and *measuring* a performance problem are two entirely different things. Build first. Measure. Then optimize. I hope you end up with fewer migraine headaches than I have.

Comment: Have you considered to use solution like [Audit.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET)? You can apply audit rules on the `DbContext` level.